# creating image tag in html and adding css

Tags: javascript

I am creating an image in jQuery like this but the border attribute doesn't seem to work... Is my syntax wrong?

```
    var img =
         $('<img>', {
            'title': 'Event  (Event '+wavy_counter+')',
            'class': 'listed_event',
            'id': 'wavy_event_'+wavy_counter+'',
            'data-count': ''+wavy_counter+'',
            'src': 'final_tutorial_buttons/wavy.png', 
            'height': '50', 
            'width': '50',
            'border': 'solid',
            'border': '2px',
            'border': 'red',
            'onclick': 'highlight.call(this);', 
            'data-start': '', 
            'data-end': ''
        });
```

I get a border but is black instead of red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
'style': 'border: 2px solid red',
```

It's been a long time I don't use the "native" HTML `border` attribute, but I think it only sets the border thickness. To define all the properties you want, you need CSS, hence the `style` attribute.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. If anyone wonders who down voted all the other answers, it was me, and I did it because all the other answers are wrong. FYI, you can use `css:{border:'2px solid red'}` and it will use jQuery's `.css()` method. This way you can use an object to set multiple styles.

Answer (score 2):

Try combining the definitions and using the `attr` method instead:

```
$('<img />').attr({
    /* ... definitions ... */,
    src : 'final_tutorial_buttons/wavy.png',
    style : 'border:2px solid red;',
    /* ... definitions ... */,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var img = $("<img />").attr("src","http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif").css({border: "2px solid red"});


   $("body").append(img );

});
```

​
​
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CXn6v/

Answer (score -2):

Just a suggestion: have you tried using the Hex color code for red?  #FF0000